# Prometheus not working after upgrading to Spring Boot Version 2

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, spring-boot-maven-plugin, prometheus-java

I was able to use Prometheus with the Spring Boot Version 2 before without any problem. After updating Spring Boot version to 2.1.1. Release I come across with the following error.

I upgraded Prometheus version from 0.2.0 to 0.6.0 but I still come across with the same error .

Do you think prometheus is not compatible with Spring Boot Version 2 ?

Regards

```
   Error :
   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration.propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:64)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:141)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:117)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:327)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:232)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:691)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:528)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
at com.project.projectmine.Application.main(Application.java:26)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [io.prometheus.client.spring.boot.PrometheusEndpointConfiguration] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@77556fd]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:686)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:583)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:568)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:626)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1737)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:721)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:662)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:630)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1518)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1023)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.addBeanTypeForNonAliasDefinition(BeanTypeRegistry.java:195)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.addBeanTypeForNonAliasDefinition(BeanTypeRegistry.java:159)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.addBeanType(BeanTypeRegistry.java:152)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.updateTypesIfNecessary(BeanTypeRegistry.java:140)
at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.updateTypesIfNecessary(BeanTypeRegistry.java:135)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.getNamesForType(BeanTypeRegistry.java:97)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:298)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:289)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:278)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:189)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:160)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47)
... 15 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/AbstractEndpoint
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:802)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:700)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:623)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3167)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2310)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:668)
... 37 common frames omitted
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.AbstractEndpoint
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
... 50 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the io.prometheus dependencies in your project try to use micrometer dependency which will handle the prometheus endpoint creation in your spring boot application as the support for prometheus is inbuilt in Spring Boot from version 2.X

Answer (score 1):

As it seems `simpleclient_spring`is still [referring to](https://github.com/prometheus/client_java/blob/master/simpleclient_spring_boot/pom.xml#L70) Spring Boot 1.5.

You should be using the Prometheus support from Micrometer - the backing library for actuator metrics - directly in your Spring Boot 2 application. See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-metrics.html#production-ready-metrics-export-prometheus).

You must include `micrometer-registry-prometheus` to enable the prometheus backend.